# Fatal crash when trying to add ads

Tags: android, sdk, admob, adview

I've been struggling with the new Google Ads system, I use AdMob. But it keeps crashing, whatever I try.
I've searched for solution the last few hours but nothing has worked yet. It will give a new error, or the same error.

- What I have done: I added the google-play-services-lib as a project in my Eclipse,
  and added it as a library in my project.
- I added a google ads view to my main layout:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4118138803752321/8641047294" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- I added this after my main activity:

  ```
  <activity
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
  ```
- And then I made an adrequest using this code:

  ```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
      adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
  ```

And now it's throwing errors:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oll62.png](http://puu.sh/7mshK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

after

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: I tried that before, but the same error came up, so I removed it again :p
But I will keep it in for now.

Comment: @BasBloem try using the schema `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` instead com.google.ads

Comment: without using this "xmlns:ads" u can't implement admob in your app :)

Comment: @BasBloem Clean & Build project?

Comment: i'm using 6.4.1 sdk and its working but soon google will stop it. do you want code of that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot the `xmlns:ads` attribute in your layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          .....^
```

Update:

Also *remove* those **xmlns** attribures from adview itself below, you just need them in layout element:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-411813xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

See also the documention here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Comment: still gives an error, I also followed that documentation, and that gave me errors too.

Comment: after removing the `xmlns` attributes from adview should work

Comment: I fixed it by adding    
`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

But now the ad is adding a black background so my whole applciation isn't visible now

Comment: It is but its nothing of the answers given, but I couldn't post my own answer because I was new or something..